# Unable to Concatenate 2 Variables

Tags: bash

I need to concatenate 2 string variables in bash on my Centos 6 machine

```
for f in *.tar.gz;
do
basename ${f%.tar.gz}
echo $basename
dbaddress='mysql/*.sql'
path="${basename}${dbaddress}"  
echo $path
tar -zxvf $f $path
done
```

The script should extract all .sql files inside basename/mysql/ directory.
But the output of my code is as follows:

```
basename

mysql/*.sql
tar: mysql/*.sql: Not found in archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

As you see, the $basename is not prepended to $dbaddress .
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referencing the `basename`variable (with `$basename`), but are never assigning it to anything, which means it reads to `bash` as a null string.  You might need to try `basename=${f%.tar.gz}`.

Comment: Thank you, It worked like a charm! But I'm wondering why echo $basename is printing correct filename.

Comment: It wasn't; it was echoing a blank line, because `$basename` was undefined.  the `basename` command is what was outputting the filename root.  See `man basename`- if you don't declare an extension, it returns the entire filename of the specified file (even if it does not exist).

Answer (score 1):

You may try this to combine two variables:

```
var1="Hello"
var2="$var1 world!"
```

But in your code, you aren't declaring the `basename` variable!